# Is there a way or workaround to insert "continue" statement in a list comprehension?

Tags: python

I wanna make a solution for this [challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/list-comprehensions) on Hackerrank using python.

my code:

- It's not valid syntax, I know but I want to make like this clue

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
            x = int(1)
            y = int(1)
            z = int(1)
            n = int(2)
            result = [[i, j, k]
                      for i in range(n)
                      for j in range(n)
                      for k in range(n)
                      if n != sum([i, j, k]) else continue] # else continue, How to achieve?
            print(result)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just omit the else completely and that element will be skipped.

Comment: the assignment is about list comprehensions - maybe study those?

Comment: BTW, there's no need to cast an integer to an integer. So `x = int(1)` should be `x = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension with only if clause -

```
[i for i in l if condition]  #list only contains items that satisfy conditon
```

List comprehension with if and else -

```
[out1 if condition1 else out2 if i in l]  #list contains out1 where the condition is met and out2 where it is not
```

Your problem is of the first type. **You are not using the right syntax for only the if clause.**